# Dynamic key Value Typing Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I need a little help here.

My API response is as below:

```
Week At A Glance: { objA: [{}], objB: [{}] },
records: { Employee Records: [{}], Email Records: [{}], message: "" },
history: { [{}] }
```

When i am trying to create a model for it as below, i am not able to proceed. I created as below

```
interface DesiredResponse {
    [key: string] : {
        objA: ObjA[],
        objB: ObjB[]
    },
    records: Records[],
    history: History[]
}

interface Records {
    [key: string]: EmpRecords | EmailRecords;
    message: string
}
```

**Typescript error:** Property 'records' of type 'Records[]' is not assignable to string index type '{ objA: BbjA[]; objB: ObjB[] }'

Property 'message' of type 'string' is not assignable to string index type 'EmpRecords | EmailRecords'

How can i efficiently type it so that i get auto suggestion while accessing this model.

Comment: Your TypeScript interfaces are invalid - you should use semicolons instead of commas when defining the properties in the interfaces (they're not like JSON, where you can use commas instead of semicolons).

Comment: @Edric not true.. both `;` and `,`are valid as separators: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN7LgLmSAVwFsAjaAGmRL0NOmQF8AoUSWRFAIU2xuLKgBuKnzpQGQA

Comment: even if i use semi colons, error is same

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Interesting observation - didn't know you could do that!

Comment: It's probably caused by the "string index type" (or the `[key: string]` portion you've defined) applying to all of the other properties in that same interface, which causes a hiccup as the types aren't the same. In this case, either set the `[key: string]`'s value to `any`, or remove it entirely.

Comment: if i set it to any then i wont get auto completions :(

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

This is actually caused by a single issue in your code where you've defined your interface to use a list version of the `Records` interface for your `records` property as compared to what your API response is actually returning (not an array - an object):

```js
interface DesiredResponse {
  // ...
  records: Records; // Originally Records[]
}
```

---

**Original answer:**

This is because defining separate properties in a TypeScript interface usually requires you to use semicolons instead of commas, unlike that of JSON where you could do the opposite (aka use commas instead of semicolons):

```js
export interface MyInterface {
  property1: string;
  property2: boolean;
  // etc
}
```

vs:

```js
export interface MyInterface {
  property1: string,
  property2: boolean // Would not compile
}
```

Comment: See this.. still same https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN7LgLmSAVwFsAjaAGmRL0NOmQF8AoUSWRFAIU2xuLKgBuKnzpRGTFuGjwkyACIQAzsCgQAJgCVlABwD2IJSgxNkZ5AG0A1hACeeJWCigA5gF1keE+Z-I9JACtUPAB5QNQLN3JTXzN-AM5QwM5ImLMGaJ81BD0odSU8bRy8pUzzAAtgR1z7ZAAJKrAapmYpNlkUItz8zDTLG1rHZxB3PABRIh0ukuQAH2QJuGAAG2n8wT6iZSU4FwgHJ1cWyVYZDmQwoN7jtrO5S+5vcxvT9jkJqYhinpMX6TeUIsVmslBgGEA